# Remove tabs from within lists of a list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have 10 lists with four elements each seperated by tabs within a large list.  How do I remove the tabs, have the elements seperated within their respective lists, all within in a large list?

Comment: tabs?  Could you post your code please.

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387208/convert-a-string-to-a-array-python). This may work.

```
>>> tabbedlist = 'element0\telement1\telement2\telement3'
>>> list = tabbedlist.split('\t')
>>> list
['element0', 'element1', 'element2', 'element3']
```

This appears to also work for: `tabbedlist = 'element0      element1        element2        element3'` Where those spaces are actually tabs or at least my terminals rendering of them as spaces. (posting condenses the spaces, sorry)

So for your app:

```
tenlists = [
    'l0e0\tl0e1\tl0e2',
    'l1e0\tl1e2\tl1e3\tl1e4',
    'l2e0\tl2e2',
    'l3e0\tl3e2\tl3e3\tl3e4\tl3e5',
    'l4e0\tl4e2\tl4e3\tl4e4\tl4e5\tl4e6',
    'l5e0\tl5e2\tl5e3\tl5e4\tl5e5\tl5e6\tl5e7',
]

largelist = []
for list in tenlists:
        largelist.append( list.split('\t') )

print largelist
```

Answer (score 1):

To split a single list, use a list comprehension:

```
[x.split("\t") for x in list_with_tabbed_elements]
```

Now, you need to do this for each element of your list of lists. You could use another list comprehensions, but personally I don't like nested list comprehensions, so I'd suggest to use map here:

```
map(lambda l: [x.split('\t') for x in l], list_of_lists)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what your original data looks like from the question as it is, but perhaps this is all that you're looking for?

```
data = ["alpha\tbravo\tcharlie\tdelta",
        "one\ttwo\tthree\tfour"]

new_data = map(lambda x: x.split("\t"), data)

print new_data
```

... which produced the output:

```
[['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta'], ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question fully, so I am going to make following assumptions. Please let me know if they are correct.

Your input is of the form :

```
a = [["test\tinput"], ["test1\tinput1"]] # 10 elements.
```

Following code will create a list ['test', 'input', 'test1', 'input1']

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [x[0].split('\t') for x in a])
```

Comment: I guess he want to have `[['test', 'input'], ['test1','input1']]` as a result: "have the elements seperated within their respective lists"