# The result list contains single spaces when splitting a string with re.split("( )+") – is there a better way?

Tags: python, split, python-re

I have the output of a command in tabular form. I'm parsing this output from a result file and storing it in a string. Each element in one row is separated by one or more whitespace characters, thus I'm using regular expressions to match 1 or more spaces and split it. However, a space is being inserted between every element:

```
>>> str1 = "a    b     c      d"  # spaces are irregular
>>> str1
'a    b     c      d'
>>> str2 = re.split("( )+", str1)
>>> str2
['a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ', 'd']  # 1 space element between!
```

Is there a better way to do this?

After each split `str2` is appended to a list.

Comment: I downvoted this question. Reason is that while the question itself is relevant the given example is not hard enough to really require the requested solution. A regex would be required if you have for instance blocks of words, blocks of numbers and you want to separate them into different variables.

Comment: @erikbwork I wanted to remove the unwanted space item in resultant string `'str2'`

Comment: Yes and you can achieve that with simply using `str1.split()`. No need for a regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split Strings into words with multiple word boundary delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059559/split-strings-into-words-with-multiple-word-boundary-delimiters)

Comment: Kudos to @erikbstack for explaining a downvote. Title and body don't go together. Either the title should be about including delimiters in the re.split() output, or the body should reflect the simpler title, e.g. `['1', '2', '3'] == re.split(r'[, ]+', "1,2 3")`

Answer (score 217, accepted):

By using `(`,`)`, you are capturing the group, if you simply remove them you will not have this problem.

```
>>> str1 = "a    b     c      d"
>>> re.split(" +", str1)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

However there is no need for regex, `str.split` without any delimiter specified will split this by whitespace for you. This would be the best way in this case.

```
>>> str1.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

If you really wanted regex you can use this (`'\s'` represents whitespace and it's clearer):

```
>>> re.split("\s+", str1)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

or you can find all non-whitespace characters

```
>>> re.findall(r'\S+',str1)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: Keep it simple. `str.split` is definitely the best :D

Comment: How can I use this if I have a string that starts and ends with withspace. example: ' a b   c  de  '. For this the output comes as `['', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'de', '']`

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish `str1.split()`

Comment: @jamylak `string.split()` is an option. I was asking if it could be done with regex too?

Comment: @RakholiyaJenish Can you not use `re.findall` option?

Comment: @jamylak thanks for answer. Just didn't think of it.

Answer (score 27):

The `str.split` method will automatically remove all white space between items:

```
>>> str1 = "a    b     c      d"
>>> str1.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Docs are here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: @GururajY.S.: `str.split()` is probably the best choice for something as light-duty as this.

Answer (score 8):

When you use `re.split` and the split pattern contains capturing groups, the groups are retained in the output.  If you don't want this, use a non-capturing group instead.

Comment: Using `str.split` is probably better for your example.  I just wanted to explain why you get the behavior you do.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple actually. Try this:

```
str1="a    b     c      d"
splitStr1 = str1.split()
print splitStr1
```

Comment: I would +1 this but you are using ugly semi-colons.

Comment: @jamylak Lol. I'll change them. :) Habit of using java and python !

Comment: @GururajY.S. If you just wish to split on basis of space, you should [simply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) use `stringToSplit.split()`