# Split string by delimiter only if not wrapped in certain pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a string into a list by a delimiter (let's say `,`) but the delimiter character should be considered the delimiter only if it is not wrapped in a certain pattern, in my particular case `<>`.  IOW, when a comma is nested in `<>`, it is ignored as a delimiter and becomes just a regular character not to be delimited by.

So if I have the following string:

```
"first token, <second token part 1, second token part 2>, third token"
```

it should split into

```
list[0] = "first token"
list[1] = "second token part 1, second token part 2"
list[2] = "third token"
```

Needless to say, I cannot just do a simple split by `,` because that will split the second token into two tokens, `second token part 1` and `second token part 2`, as they have a comma in between them.

How should I define the pattern to do it using `Python RegEx`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974932/python-split-string-based-on-regular-expression

Comment: @Farhadix, that doesn't tell me how to avoid commas wrapped in `<>`

Comment: @Farhadix I don't see how that question helps the OP?

Comment: Can those patterns be nested? Are they always correctly balanced? Can they be escaped? As in `<second <nested> token with \> escaped bracket>`?

Comment: when they are nested, they are ignored as delimiters.  i.e. if a `,` is inside `<>`, it stops being a delimiter

Comment: @amphibient: Sorry, I meant the brackets ("patterns" in your question).

Comment: Do you have any data that looks like this `"part1, <part 2 <more part 2>>, part 3"`.  In other words, can the brackets nest?

Comment: @Steve, yes, but in your case there is no commas nested inside `<>`

Comment: @TimPietzcker, what do you mean by "brackets"?

Comment: but yes, `<>` can be nested inside other `<>`s.  E.g. `<part X.1<part X.2>>`

Comment: @amphibient: Then you don't have a regular language anymore, and Python regexes don't support recursion. You'll have to write a parser then (look into [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)) for that).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** Since you mentioned that the brackets may be nested, I regret to inform you that a regex solution *is not possible* in Python. The following can work only if the angle brackets are always balanced and never nested nor escaped:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "first token, <second token part 1, second token part 2>, third token"
>>> regex = re.compile(",(?![^<>]*>)")
>>> regex.split(s)
['first token', ' <second token part 1, second token part 2>', ' third token']
>>> [item.strip(" <>") for item in _]
['first token', 'second token part 1, second token part 2', 'third token']
```

The regex `,(?![^<>]*>)` splits on commas only if the next angle bracket that follows isn't a closing angle bracket.

Nested brackets preclude this or any other regex solution from working in Python. You either need a language that supports recursive regexes (like Perl or .NET languages), or use a parser.

Comment: The regex matches the commas in 'first token `,` <second token part 1 `,` <second token part 2>> `,` third token'.

Comment: @sln: Yes, that's what I wrote. No regex solution can handle nested tags (if the nesting is arbitrary). Unfortunately, the information about nesting being possible only came after I had written my answer.

Comment: Yes, no Python regex can. As you say, others can and its really trivial.

Comment: verified.  passes functionality **AND** elegance :)

Answer (score 6):

One kludgy way that works for your example is to translate the <>'s into "'s and then treat it as a CSV file:

```
import csv
import string

s = "first token, <second token part 1, second token part 2>, third token"    
a = s.translate(string.maketrans('<>', '""'))
# first token, "second token part 1, second token part 2", third token
print next(csv.reader([a], skipinitialspace=True))
['first token', 'second token part 1, second token part 2', 'third token']
```

Comment: You may want to mention (or deal with) that this precludes quotes being used elsewhere in the data.

Comment: This will not work with nested brackets.  Comments above indicate they may be nested.