# split on multiple characters in string

Tags: python, regex, string, split, attributeerror

I have a list of filenames that I need to sort based on a section within the string. However, it only works if I make the file extension part of my sorting dictionary. I want this to work if the file is a .jpg or a .png, so I am trying to split on both the '_' and the '.' character.

```
sorting = ['FRONT', 'BACK', 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'INGREDIENTS', 'INSTRUCTIONS', 'INFO', 'NUTRITION', 'PRODUCT']

filelist = ['3006345_2234661_ENG_PRODUCT.jpg', '3006345_2234661_ENG_FRONT.jpg', '3006345_2234661_ENG_LEFT.jpg', '3006345_2234661_ENG_RIGHT.jpg', '3006345_2234661_ENG_BACK.jpg', '3006345_2234661_ENG_INGREDIENTS.jpg', '3006345_2234661_ENG_NUTRITION.jpg', '3006345_2234661_ENG_INSTRUCTIONS.jpg', '3006345_2234661_ENG_INFO.jpg']

sort = sorted(filelist, key = lambda x : sorting.index(x.re.split('_|.')[3]))

print(sort)
```

This returns the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're'"

What do I need to do to split on both the _ and . when splitting out my strings for sorting? I only want to use the split for the sorting, not for re-forming the strings.

Comment: try `x.split` instead of `x.re.split`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string based on a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974932/split-string-based-on-a-regular-expression)

Comment: That gives an error "IndexError: list index out of range" which I figure means that it isn't making enough splits to get to the [3] index.

Comment: `re.split` takes position one argument as regular expression, second as data input so your syntax should be something like `re.split('_|.', x)[3]`, as mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: _"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're'"_ I'm not sure what kind of answer you expect. Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the fixed code:

```
sorted_output = sorted(filelist,key=lambda x: sorting.index(re.split(r'_|\.',x)[3]))
```

The string input to `re.split()` should be passed as the second argument to the function; you do not call `re.split()` on a string. The first argument is the regular expression itself which you had correct.

Also: you need to escape the `.` with a `\` because the full-stop or period is a special character in regular expressions which matches everything.

Output:

```
In [13]: sorted(filelist,key=lambda x: sorting.index(re.split(r'_|\.',x)[3]))                       
Out[13]: 
['3006345_2234661_ENG_FRONT.jpg',
 '3006345_2234661_ENG_BACK.jpg',
 '3006345_2234661_ENG_LEFT.jpg',
 '3006345_2234661_ENG_RIGHT.jpg',
 '3006345_2234661_ENG_INGREDIENTS.jpg',
 '3006345_2234661_ENG_INSTRUCTIONS.jpg',
 '3006345_2234661_ENG_INFO.jpg',
 '3006345_2234661_ENG_NUTRITION.jpg',
 '3006345_2234661_ENG_PRODUCT.jpg']
```

---

Edit: as @Todd mentions in the comments, if you want to additionally ensure that the strings are sorted by the numeric part *after* the first sort takes place then use:

```
sorted(filelist,key=lambda x: [sorting.index(re.split(r'_|\.',x)[3]),x])
```

Comment: This looks good. Just want to add, that if you want to sort on the numeric prefix as a secondary key, use:   [sorting.index(re.split(...)[3]), x]

Comment: @Todd: Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure I understand your code sample. Would you be able to elaborate a bit?

Comment: gladly: sorted(filelist,key=lambda x: [sorting.index(re.split(r'_|\.',x)[3]), x])  <-- I was proposing this. If the list of filenames had multiple items containing 'FRONT', this would sort them first by the indexes of *sorting* (primary key) and then alphanumerically by filename (secondary key).

Comment: Ah, nice. Got it. Updated answer to take this into account. Thanks again.