# Tokenizer method in python without using NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

New to python - I need some help figuring out how to write a tokenizer method in python without using any libraries like Nltk. How would I start? Thank you!

Comment: How exactly does your input look like? In generally you can use ```example_string.split()``` to retrieve a list of words (without an argument, this is split by whitespace).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity you can simply use the string `split` function.

```py
# Words independent of sentences
words = raw_text.split(' ')

# Sentences and words
sentences = raw_text.split('. ')
words_in_sentences = [sentence.split(' ') for sentence in sentences]
```

If you want to do something more sophisticated you can use packages like [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), which provides support for regular expressions. [[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974932/split-string-based-on-a-regular-expression)]

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you are talking about a tokenizer for a compiler. Such tokens are usually definable by a regular language for which regular expressions/finite state automata are the natural solutions. An example:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple


Token = namedtuple('Token', ['type','value'])

def lexer(text):

    IDENTIFIER = r'(?P<IDENTIFIER>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)'
    ASSIGNMENT = r'(?P<ASSIGNMENT>=)'
    NUMBER = r'(?P<NUMBER>\d+)'
    MULTIPLIER_OPERATOR = r'(?P<MULTIPLIER_OPERATOR>[*/])'
    ADDING_OPERATOR = r'(?P<ADDING_OPERATOR>[+-])'
    WHITESPACE = r'(?P<WHITESPACE>\s+)'
    EOF = r'(?P<EOF>\Z)'
    ERROR = r'(?P<ERROR>.)' # catch everything else, which is an error

    tokenizer = re.compile('|'.join([IDENTIFIER, ASSIGNMENT, NUMBER, MULTIPLIER_OPERATOR, ADDING_OPERATOR, WHITESPACE, EOF, ERROR]))
    seen_error = False
    for m in tokenizer.finditer(text):
        if m.lastgroup != 'WHITESPACE': #ignore whitespace
            if m.lastgroup == 'ERROR':
                if not seen_error:
                    yield Token(m.lastgroup, m.group())
                    seen_error = True # scan until we find a non-error input
            else:
                yield Token(m.lastgroup, m.group())
                seen_error = False
        else:
            seen_error = False
                

for token in lexer('foo = x12 * y / z - 3'):
    print(token)
```

Prints:

```
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='foo')
Token(type='ASSIGNMENT', value='=')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='x12')
Token(type='MULTIPLIER_OPERATOR', value='*')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='y')
Token(type='MULTIPLIER_OPERATOR', value='/')
Token(type='IDENTIFIER', value='z')
Token(type='ADDING_OPERATOR', value='-')
Token(type='NUMBER', value='3')
Token(type='EOF', value='')
```

The above code defines each token such as `IDENTIFIER`, `ASSIGNMENT`, etc. as simple regular expressions and then combines them into a single regular expression pattern using the `|` operator and compiles the expression as variable `tokenizer`. It then uses the regular expression `finditer` method with the input text as its argument to create a "scanner" that tries to match successive input tokens against the `tokenizer` regular expression. As long as there are matches, `Token` instances consisting of type and value are yielded by the `lexer` generator function. In this example, `WHITESPACE` tokens are not yielded on the assumption that whitespace is to be ignored by the parser and only serves to separate other tokens.

There is a catchall `ERROR` token defined as the last token that will match a single character if none of the other token regular expressions match (a `.` is used for this, which will not match a newline character unless flag `re.S` is used, but there is no need to match a newline since the newline character is being matched by the `WHITESPACE` token regular expression and is therefor a "legal" match). Special code is added to prevent successive `ERROR` tokens being generated. In effect, the `lexer` generates an `ERROR` token and then throws away input until it can once again match a legal token.

Answer (score 0):

use gensim instead.

`tokenized_word = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentences ), deacc=True) # deacc=True removes punctuations`