# Python String split using a regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

We want to split a string multi line for example

```
|---------------------------------------------Title1(a)---------------------------------------------

Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

|---------------------------------------------Title1(b)----------------------------------------------

Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

here's our python split using regex code

```
import re

str1 = "|---------------------------------------------Title1(a)---------------------------------------------" \
    "" \
    "Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" \
    "" \
    "|---------------------------------------------Title1(b)----------------------------------------------" \
    "" \
    "Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" \
    "|"

print(str1)

str2 = re.split("\|---------------------------------------------", str1)


print(str2)
```

We want the output to include only

`str2[0]`:

```
Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

`str2[1]`:

```
Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

what's the proper regex to use, or is there any other way to split using the format above

Comment: Maybe `re.split(r'\s*^\|---.*\s*', text)`? You will still need to get rid of the first empty item though. Also, the `str1` does not contain line breaks in your code.

Comment: Maybe all you want is all non-blank lines not starting with `|---`? `str2 = [line for line in str1.splitlines() if not line.startswith('|---') and line.strip()]`

Comment: You could use `\|-+Title\d+\([a-z]\)-+(.+?)(?=\||$)` https://regex101.com/r/R6kwim/1 Then use re.findall and get the values by index if you want. See https://ideone.com/vHbRSa

Comment: Or if there has to be a `|` at the end and a any other char than - for title and content `\|-{2,}[^-]+-{2,}([^-].*?)(?=\|)`https://regex101.com/r/J501Ea/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string based on a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974932/split-string-based-on-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using split, you can match the lines and capture the part that you want in a group.

```
\|-{2,}[^-]+-{2,}([^-].*?)(?=\|)
```

**Explanation**

- `\|` Match `|`
- `-{2,}` Match 2 or more `-`
- `[^-]+` Match 1+ times any char except `-`
- `-{2,}` Match 2 or more `-`
- `(` Capture grou 1

  - `[^-].*?` match any char except `-`, then any char as least as possible
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?=\|)` Positive lookahead, assert a `|` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J501Ea/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/epfw3o)

**Example**

```
import re
 
regex = r"\|-{2,}[^-]+-{2,}([^-].*?)(?=\|)"
 
str1 = "|---------------------------------------------Title1(a)---------------------------------------------" \
    "" \
    "Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" \
    "" \
    "|---------------------------------------------Title1(b)----------------------------------------------" \
    "" \
    "Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" \
    "|"
 
str2 = re.findall(regex, str1);
print(str2[0])
print(str2[1])
```

**Output**

```
Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Content goes here, the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

---

If `Title` should be part of the line, another option is to make the match a bit more precise.

```
\|-+Title\d+\([a-z]\)-+(.+?)(?=\||$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R6kwim/1)

Comment: I still think regex is definitely overkill here. `str2 = [line for line in str1.splitlines() if not line.startswith('|---') and line.strip()]` looks to be [working well](https://ideone.com/9ISorj) for this type of content.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I will check later on, I am offline for the next hours. But your solutions look good :-) If you post it you have my vote.