# Splitting a string on non digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I am trying to split a string on any char that is not a digit.

```
orig = '0 1,2.3-4:5;6d7'
results = orig.split(r'\D+')
```

I expect to get a list of integers in `results`

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

but instead I am getting a list with a single string element which matches the original string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python split string based on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/python-split-string-based-on-regex)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well ... you are using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)  - which takes characters to split at - not regex. Your code would split on any `'\D+'` - string inside your text:

```
orig = 'Some\\D+text\\D+tosplit'
results = orig.split(r'\D+')  # ['Some', 'text', 'tosplit']
```

You can use [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) instead:

```
import re

orig = '0 1,2.3-4:5;6d7'
results = re.split(r'\D+',orig)
print(results)
```

to get

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Use `data = list(map(int,results))` to convert to int.

Comment: If you want to get non-digit and digit sections, you can add group to regex:
`re.split(r'(\D+)', orig)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
orig = '0 1,2.3-4:5;6d7'
[i for i in orig if i.isdigit()]
```

Comment: nice one - although if you have numbers with more then one digit (`'12 142, 92'`) you will get `[1,2,1,4,2,9,2]` instead of `[12,142,92]`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes, I noticed that. but maybe it works for OP

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in '0 1,2.3-4:5;6d7':
    try:
        print(int(i),end=' ')
    except:
        continue
```

## 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: That is not "splitting" a list. You are just printing the numbers.

Comment: create a list, l=[], then in try/catch block '' l.append(int(i)) '' instead print(int(i)).