# How to account for special characters when splitting string in python

Tags: python, split

I have several strings of the form "[one or more words] [number] [one or more words]" and I want to split them into the two strings and the number. For example, if the string is:

```
"A sample string 20 something"
```

I want to obtain:

```
str1 = "A sample string"
numb = 20
str2 = 'something'
```

I have (almost) achieved my goal with the following code:

```
for s in row.split():
    if s.isdigit():
        quants = s
temp = row.split("{}".format(quants))
str1 = temp[0].strip()
str2 = temp[1].strip()
```

this works fine for most cases. However, there are 2 exceptions which I'm not able to handle:

1. If the number is inside brackets, I want it to be counted as a string. For example:

   "Some text (just as 1 example) 2 more words"

   I want to have str1 = "Some text (just as 1 example)"
2. Sometimes the number is expressed in special character (Unicode?), ¼, ½ and ¾. How do I account for these?

I suspect the answer is to use regular expressions rather than a delimiter, but I could not really grasp how to use them yet.

Comment: Some remarks: 1) `split()` will not help you; your solution just works for single-digit numbers 2) The requirement to consider numbers in brackets as text requires a different approach. 3) With a proper encoding statement, you can include fractions the same way in code as in your question.

Comment: 1) actually my solution works also with numbers that have more than 1 digit, as long as there are no spaces in between them, which satisfies the characteristics of the strings I have to deal with. 2) what approach? 3) what do you mean by encoding statement? Those are not just fractions, but unicode(?) characters (i.e. ¼ not 1/4)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer to fit your needs better, except for the special characters, do you mean `&frac12;` = 1/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a regex with 3 capturing groups, and then get the values of the groups.

```
^(\w+(?: \w+)*(?: \([^()]*\))?) (\d+|[¼½¾]) (\w+(?: \w+)*)$
```

*Explanation*

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+(?: \w+)*` Match 1+ word chars, optionally repeated by space and 1+ word chars
  - `(?: \([^()]*\))?` Optionally match a space and form opening till closing parenthesis
- `)`  Close group and match the space
- `(\d+|[¼½¾])`  Capture **group 2** Match 1+ digits or 1 of the listed `¼½¾` and space
- `(\w+(?: \w+)*)` Capture **group 3** Match 1+ word chars, and optionally repeat that preceded by space
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yqsQ4c/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Gl1JmZ)

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"(\w+(?: \w+)*(?: \([^()]*\))?) (\d+|[¼½¾]) (\w+(?: \w+)*)"
s = "Some text (just as 1 example) ¼ more words"
match = re.match(regex, s)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
    print(match.group(2))
    print(match.group(3))
```

Output

```
Some text (just as 1 example)
¼
more words
```

---

A bit broader pattern that uses `.*` to match any char except a newline instead of using `\w+`

```
^(.*(?:\([^()]*\))?) (\d+|[¼½¾]) (.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NxK7JK/1)

Comment: Perfect! Also the regex demo tool is amazing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I adjusted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/python-split-string-based-on-regex/13209453) answer by replacing the regex by numbers

```
import re
l = re.compile("((?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?=\d)(?<=\D))(?![^\(]*\))").split(test)
```

gave me this:

```
['A sample string ', '20', ' something']
```

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/zT2dF9/53

where as `((?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?=\d)(?<=\D))` can be separated into two steps:
(?<=\d)(?=\D) is a lookbehind of digits (done by `(?<=\d)`) followed by non-digits of any kind `(?=\D)'

And vice versa `(?=\d)(?<=\D)` searches for non-digits followed by digits

This is concatenated by `(?![^\(]*\))` to ignore the content in brackets

For detailed information about the regex literals, check this out: https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285

Comment: would you be so kind to explain this? My code can already decompose a string in this way. Can this code handle the two exceptions I mentioned above?