# How to code a regex pattern for multiple identical characters in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, split

I have a long string of the following form:

```
joined_string = "ASOGHFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGFIOSGFFFFFFFFURHDHREEKFFFFFFIIIEI..."
```

it is a concatenation of random strings interspersed by strings of consecutive `F` letters:

```
ASOGH
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
GFIOSG
FFFFFFFF
URHDHREEK
FFFFFF
IIIEI
```

The number of consecutive `F` letters is not fixed, but there will be more than 5,
and lets assume five `F` letters will not appear in random strings consecutively.

I want to extract only random strings to get the following list:

```
random_strings = ['ASOGH', 'GFIOSG', 'URHDHREEK', 'IIIEI']
```

I imagine there is a simple regex expression that would solve this task:

```
random_strings = joined_string.split('WHAT_TO_TYPE_HERE?')
```

**Question**: how to code a regex pattern for multiple identical characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string based on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/split-string-based-on-regex)

Comment: `str.split` cannot take a regex so use the `re` module with the pattern `F+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) for this task following way

```
import re
joined_string = "ASOGHFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGFIOSGFFFFFFFFURHDHREEKFFFFFFIIIEI"
parts = re.split('F{5,}',joined_string)
print(parts)
```

output

```
['ASOGH', 'GFIOSG', 'URHDHREEK', 'IIIEI']
```

`F{5,}` denotes 5 or more `F`

Answer (score 1):

You can use split using `F{5,}` and keep this in capture group so that split text is also part of result:

```sh
import re
s = "ASOGHFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGFIOSGFFFFFFFFURHDHREEKFFFFFFIIIEI"
print( re.split(r'(F{5,})', s) )
```

**Output:**

`['ASOGH', 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF', 'GFIOSG', 'FFFFFFFF', 'URHDHREEK', 'FFFFFF', 'IIIEI']`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex find all approach here:

```
joined_string = "ASOGHFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFGFIOSGFFFFFFFFURHDHREEKFFFFFFIIIEI"
parts = re.findall(r'F{2,}|(?:[A-EG-Z]|F(?!F))+', joined_string)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['ASOGH', 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF', 'GFIOSG', 'FFFFFFFF', 'URHDHREEK', 'FFFFFF', 'IIIEI']
```

The regex pattern here can be explained as:

```regex
F{2,}         match any group of 2 or more consecutive F's (first)
|             OR, that failing
(?:
    [A-EG-Z]  match any non F character
    |         OR
    F(?!F)    match a single F (not followed by an F)
)+            all of these, one or more times
```