# How do I split sentence on 'and'?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to split my sentence on 'and' but some of the results looks like this

My code

```
string = 'I am handling it because it is difficult and confusing'

string.split('and')
```

Results

```
['I am h', 'ling it because it is difficult ', ' confusing']
```

I am trying to get this. How do I do it?

```
['I am handling it because it is difficult ', ' confusing']
```

Comment: You could split on `' and '` (with spaces) instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string based on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/split-string-based-on-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
string.split(" and ")
```

It will only pick the word.
But if you need spaces, this function/loop will do(tested):

```
add_spaces(x): 
    x[0] += ' '
    for i in range(1, len(x) - 1):
        x[i] = ' ' + x[i]
        x[i] += ' '
    x[-1] = ' ' +  x[-1]
```