# How do I convert string to list in Python?

Tags: python

How do I convert ***def stringParametre(x)*** x to a list so that if x is hello then it will become a list like ["H","E","l","l","O"] . Capitals don't matter .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert a string to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387208/convert-a-string-to-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

Note that you do not have to convert to a list if all you want to do is to iterate over the characters of the string:

```
for c in "hello":
     # do something with c
```

works

Answer (score 2):

Building on @idjaw's comment:

```
def stringParametre(x):
    return list(x)
```

Of course this will have an error if `x` is not a string (or other sequence type).

Comment: correction: will raise an error if x is not iterable, will obviously not give desired results if x is not a `str`

Answer (score 2):

```
list(x)
```

OR

```
mylist = []
for c in x:
    mylist.append(c)
```