# convert list with arrays from csv file into floats

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with list of samples of various parameters of accelerometer and gyroscopic data. It contains floats(IQR,Range,MAD,...) and arrays(ZCD values). When I read it back, they are returned as strings and for my processing,I need numbers (int/float).
I tried

```
    results = map(int, results)
```

and

```
results = [int(i) for i in results]
```

I got them from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368789/convert-all-strings-in-a-list-to-int), but I am having a problem with the arrays.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/pi/Desktop/imu/mpu_v16.py", line 458, in <module>
  main()
 File "/home/pi/Desktop/imu/mpu_v16.py", line 439, in main
  compare()
 File "/home/pi/Desktop/imu/mpu_v16.py", line 305, in compare
  nrow = [float(i) for i in nrow]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: [ 53  73  79 139]
```

How can I solve this?

I am adding a sample of my data:

```
    C,3.3440452548950501e-17,0.99999999999999645,0.89244290726827058,1.7947499048650259,3.3651560716219242,[108 123 149 220 235],0.99999999999999822,110223.99999999971,331.99999999999915,-5.9524005537131887e-17,0.99999999999999989,0.81051947660768831,1.4756039753111405,4.4268119259334213,[103 122 160 205 212],0.99999999999999989,110224.00000000001,332.00000000000006,-6.4540073419474463e-17,0.999999999999999,0.74198651253618131,0.63512619216067612,4.256170326687128,[106 164 192 226],0.99999999999999933,110224.00000000001,332.00000000000006,2.083131190971185e-16,1.0000000000000009,0.66659374901400581,0.52759419283475883,4.5104130995285256,[  7  14  45  56 150 327],1.0000000000000002,110223.99999999994,331.99999999999983,-3.0890618042093025e-17,0.99999999999999667,0.58289607514346964,0.21669963911591134,4.7919240951669444,[ 82 149 208],0.99999999999999822,110223.99999999942,331.99999999999824,-3.2771643497971487e-16,1.0000000000000009,0.58746356061392535,0.29681486739557372,5.2741718744905794,[ 26  48  59  66 114 171 231 242],1.0000000000000002,110224.00000000036,332.00000000000108,-0.57536274345915739,0.147595080030029,0.13018399571123057
```

Comment: the problem I see in the error you posted is that you are trying to convert an array of strings into float, whereas you should apply int() one by one. As a quick and dirty solution, apply another for loop.

Comment: Your csv does not contain numbers, it contains space separated sequences of numbers.

Comment: Looks like you wrote numpy array to the file as strings.you will need to strip the [] and then split each line on whitespace and cast each element

Comment: post your input file data, and the code you wrote to read it

Comment: You should give a sample of your data if you are having conversion problems.

Comment: Added a sample of data. Also,I am working on the answer given by @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your input consists of strings of floats AND strings of arrays, you need a way of differentiating between the two. One way is to perhaps check the string for spaces? Then, for float strings, simply use `float(i)` like you have been doing. Then for array strings, try splitting on the spaces to separate the array elements and then running `float` on each individual string float ([convert a string to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387208/convert-a-string-to-an-array)).

Arbitrary float input: `"54.6"`
Check for spaces: `False`
Call: `float("54.6")`

Arbitrary array input: `"[ 53 73 79 139]"`
Check for spaces: `True`
Remove brackets: `" 53 73 79 139"`
Split on spaces and store in an array: `["53","73","79","139"]`
Call float on each element: `[53,73,79,139]`

Comment: ,Your solution not exactly solved my problem, but helped me somewhat.I had changed my storing method to overcome this array problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your csv is malformed, or you are reading it incorrectly. What you have extracted aren't individual numbers, it's multiple numbers boxed into brackets. See the error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: [ 53  73  79 139]
            ###              This is your data ^               ^
```

So you have a list like `["[ 53  73  79 139]", "[ 123 12 11]"]` when you should actually have `[["53", "73", "79", "139"], ["123", "12", "11"]]` or `["53", "73", "79", "139", "123", "12", "11"]`.

If your csv is malformed, you can correct this on the fly by splitting the erroneous values. This will give you a flat list like `[53, 73, 79, 139]`:

```
nrow = [float(i) for elem in nrow for i in elem.strip('[] ').split()]
#                ^              ^ extract every sequence of numbers
#                                          ^              ^ remove [] and whitespace around sequences
#                                                            ^     ^ split the actual numbers
```

This will give you a list of lists like `[[ 53, 73, 79, 139], ...]`:

```
    nrow = [[float(i) for i in elem.strip('[] ').split()] for elem in nrow ]
```