# Converting Hex string to matrix form in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, aes

I have a hex string `a = 54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f`
And I want it in the form of a matrix like this:

```
s = [[54, 4f, 4e, 20],
     [77, 6e, 69, 54],
     [6f, 65, 6e, 77],
     [20, 20, 65, 6f]]
```

How do I do it?

For more clarification: I am writing a program for AES encryption and decryption. And this is the 1st part where the plaintext is converted to hexadecimal and then to a state (4x4 matrix).

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387208/convert-a-string-to-an-array

Comment: Using the solution in that question gives me `['54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f']`

Comment: You have of course adapt it to split your hex string into chunks of 8 and divide them afterwards in 4x2.  But somebody has already been nice enough to do the coding for you.

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate as this is not about hex conversion in itself, it is mainly about re-arranging the values. But note that within cryptography, it often pays to perform these kind of operations on bytes rather than (character) strings. I good answer would convert to bytes and then rearrange *those*.

Answer (score 3):

**This should work:**

```
import numpy as np

a = '54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f'
n = 2
x = [a[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]

my_matrix = np.array(x).reshape(4, 4).T

print(my_matrix)


[['54' '4f' '4e' '20']
 ['77' '6e' '69' '54']
 ['6f' '65' '6e' '77']
 ['20' '20' '65' '6f']]
```

Comment: Voted up as I think this is the most *readable* and thus maintainable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following. Chunk the string appropriately and then use the `zip(*...)` transpositioning pattern:

```
def group(seq, n):
    return [seq[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(seq), n)]

>>> a = '54776f204f6e65204e696e652054776f'
>>> list(zip(*group(group(a, 2), 4)))
[('54', '4f', '4e', '20'), 
 ('77', '6e', '69', '54'), 
 ('6f', '65', '6e', '77'), 
 ('20', '20', '65', '6f')]
```