# Python - convert a string to an array

Tags: python, arrays, string

How would I convert the following string to an array with Python (this string could have an indefinite number of items)?

```py
'["Foo","Bar","Baz","Woo"]'
```

This is definitely a string representation as well. `type()` gave:

```py
<class 'str'>
```

---

I got it.

```py
interestedin = request.POST.get('interestedIn')[1:-1].split(',')

interested = []

for element in interestedin:
    interested.append(element[1:-1])
```

Where `request.POST.get('interestedIn')` gave the `'["Foo","Bar","Baz","Woo"]'` string list "thing".

Comment: That looks like a list, not a string...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to a list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387208/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-list-in-python)

Comment: are you talking about the element inside of this list ?

Comment: That looks like it's a duplicate question – I am sure I've seen at least several variants. Anyway, what did you try & why did it not work?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` or `json.loads()` ...

Comment: Im guessing he wants "".join(str_list), and has a very weird way of writing a question.

Comment: Making a variable by Copy/paste of your 'following string' definitely does not return a class of str when you run type(). At least on my machine.

Comment: Wow - -10 XD yes, it's definitely a string. I promise. type(my_variable) gives `<class 'str'>`. I missed off the bracing '.

Comment: *It's come from passing an array via AJAX post request.

Comment: Got it - just updated my question. Apologies for asking such a weird question! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with string '["Foo","Bar","Baz","Woo"]':

```
str = '["Foo","Bar","Baz","Woo"]'
str1 = str.replace(']', '').replace('[', '')
l = str1.replace('"', '').split(",")
print l # ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Woo'] A list
```

If you mean using the Python [array module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/array.html), then you could do like this:

```
import array as ar

x = ar.array('c')  # Character array
for i in ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Woo']: x.extend(ar.array('c', i))
print x  #array('c', 'FooBarBazWoo')
```

It will be much simpler if you consider using [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) though:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array(['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Woo'])
print y #  ['Foo' 'Bar' 'Baz' 'Woo']
```

Comment: First option ruins your data if any of the elements contain a [ or ] as part of its own text. Second and third options do not start from a string and have nothing to do to string to array or list conversion.

Answer (score 22):

You can do this

```
import ast

list = '["Foo","Bar","Baz","Woo"]'
list = ast.literal_eval(list)
print list
```

Comment: @GCien This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: That seems the way to go to [get the *Life boat* badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8842/lifeboat?page=1): Add an answer without any explanation [whatsoever](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Answer (score 7):

#### No-package solution

You can use the [eval](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#eval) function:

```
list = eval('["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Woo"]')
print (list)

# ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Woo']
```

#### Alternative solution

Based on [baptx's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50023635/python-convert-a-string-to-an-array#comment120581438_63780901), an alternative way (probably a better one) is to use the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) package:

```
from ast import literal_eval

list = literal_eval('["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Woo"]')
print (list)

# ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Woo']
```

Comment: It looks like this can be dangerous if the data is untrusted since it can execute code, I read it is recommended to use `ast.literal_eval` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval

Comment: Though this answer is about Python (about which, I admit, know nothing), not about PHP, but even so... I still believe that this statement is true even for Python: "_Rasmus Lerdorf, the creator of PHP, once wrote that »if eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question«_"!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```py
import json

json.loads('["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Woo"]')
```